# VUE JS: If I had a string such as "8^3", how would I store 8 and 3 as two separate variables?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a calculator using VUE JS. I was wondering how to do exponents in that if I had something like "8^3", how would I split the string into the two separate digits?

Comment: Please provide more context. Generally there is [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) but I get the feeling you need a more universal solution here

Comment: Please do some research before asking a new question. Finding the answer to such a basic question is usually just a quick search away.